# python list comprehension not working as expected

Tags: python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I am new to list comprehension in python . I am tying to convert a for-if statement to list comprehension but it is not working as expected:

```
a = ['Done', 'add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11']
record = "addRec"
```

Normal python code:

```
list_new = []    
for member in a:
  if record and "addRec" in member:
    list_new.append(member)
    print(list_new)
```

My list comprehension:

```
list_new = [list_new.append(member) for member in a if record and "addRec" in member]
```

list_new is returning as a empty list.

It should return :

```
['add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11']
```

Comment: what does record represent?

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comperhension already return a list, so I think that the list_new.append(member) is redundant.

I reproduced your code without the "record" and without the append part. It seems to be working:

```
a = ['Done', 'add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11']
list_new = []
for member in a:
  if "addRec" in member:
    list_new.append(member)
    print(list_new)
assert ['add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11'] == list_new

#comperhension
list_new = [member for member in a if "addRec" in member]
print list_new
assert ['add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11'] == list_new
```

EDIT (adding "record" after question edit):

```
a = ['Done', 'add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11']
record = "addRec"

list_new = []
for member in a:
  if record and "addRec" in member:
    list_new.append(member)
    print(list_new)
assert ['add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11'] == list_new

#comperhension
list_new = [member for member in a if record and "addRec" in member]
print list_new
assert ['add dns addRec test 11.11.11.11'] == list_new
```

Comment: The `record` condition isn't doing anything, because record == "addRec" and so is truelike.  I'm not sure if it was originally something different, and the OP wanted `if record in member and "addRec" in member:` or not, but right now, it's pointless.

Comment: I agree, record is useless as it appears in the question, but it might just be an example for its value. in any case my answer contains a solution for both cases (with or without record)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list_new = [member for member in a if record and "addRec" in member]
```

Note that the `.append()` function doesn't return anything.